# Meteor template helper & document.write issue

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am looking to display a simple javascript calendar within a meteor-ionic template. I have the page setup correctly but when I write in the template helper: return document.write(buildCal(...)) the calendar hijacks the page and none of the other elements display. When I just code return buildCal(.....), it just prints out the all of the divs and not html. Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

calendar.js

```
function buildCal(m, y, cM, cH, cDW, cD, brdr) {
    var mn = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var dim = [31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

    var oD = new Date(y, m - 1, 1); //DD replaced line to fix date bug when current day is 31st
    oD.od = oD.getDay() + 1; //DD replaced line to fix date bug when current day is 31st

    var todaydate = new Date() //DD added
    var scanfortoday = (y == todaydate.getFullYear() && m == todaydate.getMonth() + 1) ? todaydate.getDate() : 0 //DD added

    dim[1] = (((oD.getFullYear() % 100 != 0) && (oD.getFullYear() % 4 == 0)) || (oD.getFullYear() % 400 == 0)) ? 29 : 28;
    var t = '<div class="' + cM + '"><table class="' + cM + '" cols="7" cellpadding="0" border="' + brdr + '" cellspacing="0"><tr align="center">';
    t += '<td colspan="7" align="center" class="' + cH + '">' + mn[m - 1] + ' - ' + y + '</td></tr><tr align="center">';
    for (s = 0; s < 7; s++) t += '<td class="' + cDW + '">' + "SMTWTFS".substr(s, 1) + '</td>';
    t += '</tr><tr align="center">';
    for (i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
        var x = ((i - oD.od >= 0) && (i - oD.od < dim[m - 1])) ? i - oD.od + 1 : '&nbsp;';
        if (x == scanfortoday) //DD added
            x = '<span id="today">' + x + '</span>' //DD added
        t += '<td class="' + cD + '">' + x + '</td>';
        if (((i) % 7 == 0) && (i < 36)) t += '</tr><tr align="center">';
    }
    return t += '</tr></table></div>';
}

Template.calendar.helpers({
    currentcalendar: function() {
        var todaydate = new Date();
        var curmonth = todaydate.getMonth() + 1; //get current month (1-12)
        var curyear = todaydate.getFullYear(); //get current year
        return document.write(buildCal(curmonth, curyear, "main", "month", "daysofweek", "days", 1));
    }
});
```

calendar.html

```
<template name="calendar">
  {{#contentFor "headerButtonLeft"}}
    {{>ionNavBackButton path="index"}}
  {{/contentFor}}

  {{#contentFor "headerTitle"}}
    <h1 class="title">Calendar</h1>
  {{/contentFor}}

  {{#ionView}}
    {{#ionContent}}
      {{currentcalendar}}
    {{/ionContent}}
  {{/ionView}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return `buildCal()` instead of `document.write(buildCal())` - you almost never use `document.write()` in Meteor, templates give you dynamic content.

Comment: I had done that before posting and the html code would just be printed to screen. ie not interpreted as HTML. if that makes sense.

Comment: In that case either return a `safeString` or use triple-braces `{{{currentCalendar}}}`

Comment: Triple handlebars worked! {{{currentCalendar}}}. Thanks Michel!